# Get lattitude and longitude from geotiff file in javascript

Tags: javascript, geotiff-tiff, angularjs

I need to get lattitude and logitude (geo location) information from geotiff files in javascript.

I am currently using angular 1.x technology to develop geo friendly application.

Please let me know if we have any other third party libraries to get geo information from tiff format files.